# MYSQL order by date of a datetime column

Tags: mysql

I need to sort products by 3 different fields

1. order by created at but using just the Date not the Time
2. within every day get the featured == 1 first

So I need to order by every day first and then get the featured before the non featured once.

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY ...., featured DESC;
```

As you can see I miss the part with the date and I cannot find a solution for that.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can do

```
SELECT * FROM products 
ORDER BY date(created_at),
         featured <> 1;
```

and generally this works for all DB engines

```
SELECT * FROM products 
ORDER BY date(created_at) ASC,
         case when featured = 1 then 1 else 0 end DESC;
```